# How to update adapter list based on button click android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to user perfect answer for update some item values on button click. I have an list in which contains:

```
{"fname":"fname1", "lname":"lname1","id":"1", "message":"helllo india","follow":false},
{"fname":"fname2", "lname":"lname2","id":"2", "message":"helllo asia","follow":true},
{"fname":"fname1", "lname":"lname1","id":"1", "message":"helllo world","follow":false},
{"fname":"fname3", "lname":"lname3","id":"3", "message":"helllo universe","follow":false},
{"fname":"fname1", "lname":"lname1","id":"1", "message":"helllo galaxy","follow":false},
```

This list is coming from server and no of posts are dynamic.

and in adapter when user click follow button, I want to update value in list too. For single item I am updating like below:

private List modalDataList;

```
holder.followBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ModalDataModal dataModal = modalDataList.get(position);
        dataModal.setFollow(true);
        modalDataList.set(position, dataModal);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
});
```

and its working properly. But how can I update all follow status for same ids.

For ex:

If i click on button to follow for id:1 then I want to change flog for all data related to that id. Like on facebook/twitter or any other social site.

I tried to explain in simple way, my actual code is complex. So if any more code/info required, plz let me know.

Comment: use for loop and match id's where id'd match set the model of your model class

Comment: is this only way...as for long list for loop might be took some time